# apollo-client used to make multiple requests to make a real-time search

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

We're developing a search engine inside an app with Apollo and we do not know exactly how to develop a real-time search engine that makes a request to the server on every keyboard press.

On the documentation it says that we must use the new `<Query />` component, but I see that this case mostly fits with firing a manual query: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query

I don't know if I'm correct, or maybe we should use it in another way.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said at a link you shared, if you wanted to delay firing your query until the user performs an action (your case), such as clicking on a button, you want to use an `ApolloConsumer` component and directly call `client.query()` instead.

`Query` component can't be used in this situation because when React mounts a `Query` component, Apollo Client automatically fires off your query during rendering.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

With Apollo Client V2.6, it is now possible to make a Query to the server manually using a hook. The hook that you want is [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#uselazyquery).

You'd have something like this;

```js
const [onSearch, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
    SEARCH_QUERY,
    { variables: { searchText: state.searchText } }
  );
```

Then you can call the `onSearch` function whenever your text changes inside a `useEffect` like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
onSearch()
}, [state.searchText])
```

Note that you might want to `dounce` your `onSearch` function such that you don't hammer your server on every key stroke.